# Do Ubuntu snappy packages need much more space?

Tags: disk-usage, ubuntu-core, click-packages

Actually I thought that one of the benefits of a Linux system are the shared dependencies, which makes individual programs small in space. GIMP needs 15 MB disk space, the requirements for Photoshop are 2 GB.

When Ubuntu switches to snappy packages which bring there own libraries, won't they also need a hell lot of space?

Answer (score 2):

> When Ubuntu switches to snappy packages which bring there own libraries, won't they also need a hell lot of space?

Nope (well probably not). Libraries tend to be small anyways but a Snappy application is basically a single **compressed** archive package with all the files contained for the app to run. So the libraries are compressed as well making them a few KB.

But I agree it's a different approach from the shared library vision where 1 library is used across the system. I consider it a small price to pay for the other benefits: snappy lets you install different versions next to each other (it has a "current" symlink pointing to the active version) so rollbacks are just a change to the symlink. It is a big improvement regarding security (it is a container and most/all of snappy files are readonly).

I do wonder what the method will be if there is a bug in 1 of those libraries and tons of apps need to be updated... (how would they do that? I hope they do not create a new version for every app **:P**)

> GIMP needs 15 MB disk space, the requirements for Photoshop are 2 GB.

That's not necessarily due to shared libraries.